# With Swing & Java, what is done by the "Swing-Shell" thread

Tags: java, swing, file, multithreading

with threads & swing, the event queue (event dispatch thread) is broadly presented & discussed.

However, when examining the thread states with a Swing application, there's also a thread named *Swing-Shell*. With brief googling I couldn't find much details, mostly thread stack traces with bug reports etc.

Can somebody describe shortly what that thread does. Or even better, does somebody have some link to some documentations

EDIT: I was asking too fast without enough details, sorry. I was going though various
JFileChooser issues and a thread named "Swing-Shell" occurs there, having
something to do with Windows COM services for file system.
A sample stack trace within a deadlock problem can be found at
[Sun Bug #6741890](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6741890).
(The thread stack trace starts with *sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker$3.run*).

With closer inspection with [jconsole](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jconsole.html), I noticed that the thread isn't present there until
I have used JFileChooser (JFileChooser for example; the Swing-Shell thread will probably be started
by any components using Win32ShellFolderManager)
The thread seems to exist also after the usage of JFileChooser.

So, answering to myself, the thread seems to be a separate thread used for COM services with
file-related operations (with Windows only? ). If somebody can provide more details, welcome =)

Comment: When you do a thread dump, what does the stack trace look like for that thread?

Comment: And to clarify, if you start your swing application from a command line on Windows then you can hit Ctrl-Break in that command line while the application is running (note: not Ctrl-C) to get the stack traces of every running thread.  There is a way to do this on Linux too but I don't remember off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

The number, purpose and naming of initial threads is [implementation dependent](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). On my platform, the [event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (EDT) is named `AWT-EventQueue-0`.

Addendum: The only other [reference](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/embedjava/) I found says, "A Motif application uses a shell widget to communicate with the window manager." Are you using a Swing library of some kind?

As suggested above, a thread dump might be illuminating. Recent versions of NetBeans' profiler include a save button; I've attached a snapshot of the threads in a typical [busy demo](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/buttons).

[image]

Comment: Yes, I got my EDT with a similar name but this "Swing-Shell" doesn't seem to be a "initial thread" (at least in the sens of the link). To me it seems to be more like a some background daemon thread of Swing or something..